# run `make qemu` got error: `qemu_mprotect__osdep: mprotect failed: Permission denied`

Tags: linux, qemu, riscv, apple-m1, mprotect

I am trying do mit6.828 lab on **mac m1**. After installed `riscv-tool-chain`, I tried to run `make qemu` which seems to be used start the kernel, but at first I got this error:

```sh
mkfs/mkfs fs.img README user/xargstest.sh user/_cat user/_echo user/_forktest user/_grep user/_init user/_kill user/_ln user/_ls user/_mkdir user/_rm user/_sh user/_stressfs user/_usertests user/_wc user/_zombie user/_cowtest user/_uthread user/_call user/_testsh user/_kalloctest user/_bcachetest user/_alloctest user/_bigfile
nmeta 46 (boot, super, log blocks 30 inode blocks 13, bitmap blocks 1) blocks 1954 total 2000
balloc: first 766 blocks have been allocated
balloc: write bitmap block at sector 45
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 1 -nographic -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0
Could not allocate dynamic translator buffer
make: *** [qemu] Error 1
```

So I clone the qemu reposiroty from the github to get the source code,and check the version to v5.1.0, then I apply the patch from this link [pathch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/qemu-devel/patch/20210103145055.11074-1-r.bolshakov@yadro.com/) which is mentioned by this [link](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1473419)

configure run as the belows:

```sh
 ./configure --disable-kvm --disable-werror --prefix=/usr/local --target-list="riscv64-softmmu"`
```

The `make` and `make install` seems work well, but when I execute `make qemu` again in the lab, it appeared another error, I still not found how to solve this problem:

```sh
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 -nographic -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0
qemu-system-riscv64: qemu_mprotect__osdep: mprotect failed: Permission denied
**
ERROR:/Users/rezero/Desktop/6.828-note/qemus/qemu-5.1.0/tcg/tcg.c:733:tcg_region_init: assertion failed: (!rc)
Bail out! ERROR:/Users/rezero/Desktop/6.828-note/qemus/qemu-5.1.0/tcg/tcg.c:733:tcg_region_init: assertion failed: (!rc)
make: *** [qemu] Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Do you run MacOS Big Sur? Which exact vesrion?

Comment: macos big sur, 11.2.3

Answer (score 1):

I tried many times since I not familiar about the qemu and macos.
And here I got:

```sh
# modify /etc/paths 
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin

# modify .zshrc
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain/bin"
```

Still do not know what happened, but things seems worked after I apply two patches as the below. (Ensure close Rosetta mode on iterm, still using qemu 5.1.0)

[patch1](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/qemu-devel/patch/20210103145055.11074-1-r.bolshakov@yadro.com/) you can just download and cd to the qemu directory then command like this: `patch -p1 < ../patch/v2-tcg-Fix-execution-on-Apple-Silicon.patch`

[patch2](https://gist.github.com/stefannilsson/8a083e07f4103af2520e87fdb1f50efc/revisions) only two lines, just open the osdep.c file and modify it.

And after apply the above patches, run configure with:

`./configure --disable-kvm --disable-werror --prefix=/usr/local --target-list="riscv64-softmmu"`

and `make & make install`

Then it worked, and kernal could start.

Comment: looks like its the effect of patch2? plus...how to close Rosetta mode on iterm thx

Comment: https://www.macworld.com/article/338843/how-to-force-a-native-m1-mac-app-to-run-as-an-intel-app-instead.html @Liu Charles

Answer (score 0):

@Rezero follow your step, have you encountered such error when compile:

```
 CC      hw/display/virtio-gpu-3d.o
hw/display/virtio-gpu-3d.c:149:41: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct virgl_renderer_resource_info'
    struct virgl_renderer_resource_info info;
                                        ^
hw/display/virtio-gpu-3d.c:149:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct virgl_renderer_resource_info'
    struct virgl_renderer_resource_info info;
           ^
hw/display/virtio-gpu-3d.c:167:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'virgl_renderer_resource_get_info' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Comment: no, but it seems like error caused by your gcc version not matched..

Answer (score 0):

it is macOS 11.2 mprotect bug, you can modify qemu/tcg/tcg.c fix it, view https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/commit/c118881ee607dcac